# Sharepoint 2013 Query very slow

Tags: sharepoint-2013

we set up a new SharePoint 2013 Server to test how it would work as Document-Storage. 
The Problem is, that it is very slow and I dont know why..
I adapted from msdn:

```
    ClientContext _ctx;

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _ctx = new ClientContext("http://testSP1");
            Web web = _ctx.Web;

            Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
            w.Start();

            List list = _ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Test");
            Debug.WriteLine(w.ElapsedMilliseconds); //24 first time, 0 second time
            w.Restart();

            CamlQuery q = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(10);

            ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(q);
            _ctx.Load(items);
            _ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            Debug.WriteLine(w.ElapsedMilliseconds); //1800 first time, 900 second Time
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

There arent very much Documents in the Test list. 
Just 3 Folders and 1 Word-File. 
Any suggestions/ideas why it is this slow?

Answer (score 0):

Storing unstructured content (Word docs, PDFs, anything except metadata) in SharePoint's SQL content database is going to result in slower upload and retrieval than if the files are stored on the file system. That's why Microsoft created the Remote BLOB (Binary Large Object) Storage interface to enable files to be managed in SharePoint but live on the file system or in the cloud. The bigger the files, the greater the performance hit.

There are several third-party solutions that leverage this interface, including my company's offering, Metalogix StoragePoint. You can reach out to me at trossi@metalogix.com if you would like to learn more or visit http://www.metalogix.com/Products/StoragePoint/StoragePoint-BLOB-Offloading.aspx